# In visualforce how can I have static resource css refer to another static resource image?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a situation like this http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2 - I want to have bootstrap as a static resource in my sf project. Then I want to have the datatables as another resource, but my DT_bootstrarp.css wants to refer to an image in the bootstrap package.

So for examplle in DT_bootstrarp.css, we refer to an image in bootstrap package:

```
  table.table thead .sorting { background: url('images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
```

When I try to reference this, salesforce doesnt see it because the image is packaged in another resource. I think if it was in the same resource it would work.

So does that mean the best practice is to bundle all your css/images/js into one resource.zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all of the static resources  but if they refer each other it definitely more convenient and best practice to bundle them together in one zip file. Hope it helps and you actually answered yourself basically .

Comment: thanks, was hoping their would be a better way, but I guess this will have to work for now.